# How to use like and NOT like for same field in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

TBL_Transaction type:

```
Credit
Debit
```

TBL_Account Type:

```
1 Saving Account
2 Loan Account 
3 NRI Account
```

TBL_Transaction:

```
Sr. Name         AccType   TransType  DateOfTransaction  Amount
1   mano         saving    credit     2014/12/01           5000   
2   john         Loan      Debit      2014/12/02          10000
```

I want to records which account holder credit process only,he should debit in particular dates.

Result:
Name AccountType

I try this query ,but not work

```
SELECT 
    NAME,
    ACCOUNTTYPENAME,
    ........... 
GROUP BY 
    NAME,
    ACCOUNTTYPENAME
WHERE
    TRANSACTIONTYPENAME LIKE 'CREDIT%' AND NOT LIKE 'DEBIT%'
```

Comment: just put like 'credit%' remove and not like 'debit%'

Comment: if it is *credit*, it is not *debit*, right? so why do you need to check "not like debit" at all? but i guess it would have to be along the lines of: `WHERE TRANSACTIONTYPENAME LIKE 'CREDIT%' AND TRANSACTIONTYPENAME NOT LIKE 'DEBIT%'`

Comment: Group by must be after the where clause. Also, use the column name for both conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query

```
SELECT NAME,ACCOUNTTYPENAME
WHERE TRANSACTIONTYPENAME LIKE 'CREDIT%' OR
(TRANSACTIONTYPENAME LIKE 'CREDIT%' and (TRANSACTIONTYPENAME LIKE 'DEBIT%' and DateOfTransaction ='2014/12/01'))
 GROUP BY NAME,ACCOUNTTYPENAME
```

Comment: 2014/12/01 to 2014/12/02 , 20 user only credit process,then i increase the date 2014/12/03 ,now my result 30 user credit process,This is wrong ans

Comment: Finally i got a answer,where count(case when trnanstypename like 'd%')='0'      .Thanku for tried

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT NAME,ACCOUNTTYPENAME,........... 
WHERE TRANSACTIONTYPENAME LIKE 'CREDIT%' AND TRANSACTIONTYPENAME NOT LIKE 
'DEBIT%'
GROUP BY NAME,ACCOUNTTYPENAME
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` must be after the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You do not have a `WHERE` clause in your fiddle.

Comment: You're right, I just copy and place to solve the GROUP BY and didn't check for other errors; corrected the answer

Comment: I read your comment in the wrong way and I thought you wrote that WHERE clause must be present in case of a GROUP BY ......  perhaps this morning I should have done better if I continued to sleep :)

Comment: Hah! Or another cup of coffee.

Comment: 2014/12/01 to 2014/12/02 , 20 user only  credit process,then i increase the date 2014/12/03 ,now my result 30 user credit process,This is wrong ans

Comment: Excuse me, but I do not understand what you're saying :(

Comment: Finally i got a answer,where count(case when trnanstypename like 'd%')='0'      .Thanku for tried

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to find Names with ONLY credit transactions. You can either do a sub query

```
SELECT NAME,ACCOUNTTYPENAME from tbl_Transaction
WHERE TRANSACTIONTYPENAME LIKE 'CREDIT%' AND 
Name not in
(SELECT NAME from tbl_Transaction
WHERE TRANSACTIONTYPENAME LIKE 'DEBIT%')
```

or use `apply` clause as follows

```
SELECT NAME,ACCOUNTTYPENAME from TBL_Transaction transOuter
outer apply
(
    select count(*) as totalCredit from TBL_Transaction
    where TRANSACTIONTYPENAME LIKE 'CREDIT%'
    and NAME = transOuter.Name
) credit
outer apply
(
    select count(*) as totalDebit from TBL_Transaction
    where TRANSACTIONTYPENAME LIKE 'DEBIT%'
    and NAME = transOuter.Name
) debit
WHERE 
    credit.totalCredit > 0 
    and debit.totalDebit < 1
```

Comment: 2014/12/01 to 2014/12/02 , 20 user only credit process,then i increase the date 2014/12/03 ,now my result 30 user credit process,This is wrong ans

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. This is just to give you right direction to find your answer. I hope you can use this idea and write the correct query yourself.

Comment: Finally i got a answer,where count(case when trnanstypename like 'd%')='0'      .Thanku for tried

Answer (score 0):

This is just a small syntax error.

Based on your given code example, change it to:

```
SELECT NAME,ACCOUNTTYPENAME,........... 
WHERE TRANSACTIONTYPENAME LIKE 'CREDIT%' 
      AND TRANSACTIONTYPENAME  NOT LIKE 'DEBIT%'
GROUP BY NAME,ACCOUNTTYPENAME
```

You have your group by in the wrong position. Additionally you forgotten to mention `TRANSACTIONTYPENAME` again for your second filter.

Comment: 2014/12/01 to 2014/12/02 , 20 user only credit process,then i increase the date 2014/12/03 ,now my result 30 user credit process,This is wrong ans

Comment: Well I don't know whats your question is. The only thing which comes from your question is that your code is completely wrong. Which makes me think that your an SQL trainee? Just update your question so that everyone else could understand what you try to achieve. Just one thing left. Due to the fact that you've describe something about a date or something like that, you should include the date in your `group by` and in your `select` too.

Comment: Finally i got a answer,where count(case when trnanstypename like 'd%')='0'      .Thanku for tried

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got a answer,where count(case when trnanstypename like 'd%')='0'      .Thanku for tried

Comment: This actually wouldn't work.  You can't use COUNT() in a WHERE clause.